# How to make sure that if I reinstall VS Code it does not revert to the same changes I made before uninstalling?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc

At first when I installed VS Code I was not able to get the GCC compiler or pair one. After that every time I Re-install it goes back to the same version as it was before installing. I am unable to find the files related to VS Code in my PC so I can delete them and start fresh. Please help for the same.

I want to uninstall all files related to VS Code in such a way that it installs everything fresh and not with the previous settings.